# Phalcon PHP: Dispatcher's `forward` function does not work

Tags: php, model-view-controller, php-7, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Within the `reentryAction` in my `CustomerclientController` I want to forward into the `indexAction` in case of successful validity check of the post parameters.

Unfortunately, the forward doesn't work. While debugging, I determined that the reentryAction method will be called again, instead of indexAction.

I registered a Dispatcher in my `services.php` as follows:

```
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function() use ($eventsManager) {

    $dispatcher = new MvcDispatcher();
    // Bind the eventsManager to the view component
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
    return $dispatcher;
});
```

The CustomerclientController:

```
class CustomerclientController extends Controller {
    public function reentryAction($hash) {
        // ... a lot of code
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {
            // ... a lot of code
            if ($valid) {
                $this->dispatcher->forward([
                    "customerclient",
                    "index"
                ]);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    public function indexAction() {
        //Does something wise
    }
}
```

I defined no special routes and do not use a `route.php` file.

What am I doing wrong or what did I forget?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need use MvcDispatcher?
I checked my project and I am using Dispatcher

```
$di->set('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {
    $dispatcher = new Dispatcher;
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
    return $dispatcher;
});
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess that is not the Problem. I use `use \Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher as MvcDispatcher` on top of `services.php`.

Comment: I will dive a bit deeper into this issue on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to return the dispatcher->forward(). Second, maybe write the keys in the array.

```
if ($valid) 
  return $this->dispatcher->forward([
    "controller" => "customerclient",
    "action" => "index"
  ]);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried your approach, but unfortunately the same problem occurs.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Not much to be honest. Are you your $valid returns true?